# Refused to execute 'blah blah blah Google analytics id= ****' as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, mime-types

I am trying to help a lady out who was sold a crappy Wordpress site. Trying to get her some google analytics set up so I created her a project on my analytics account and gave her the javascript code to have her 'Wordpress dev' install in the head. The code looks something like this

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=*************"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '*************');
</script>
```

Not receiving any data back from the website however due to a console error that shows the code is not executing.

Here is the error

Refused to execute https://***************.com/www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-************ as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.

Any advice on how to go about fixing this?

Thanks Stack

Read through Stack and found no relevant Analytics / Wordpress Mime Type correlations